# Featured Image meta box missing for pages in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am really hoping someone can help as this is driving me crazy.

I can't get featured images to appear on my pages in wordpress. The theme is CouponXL. I have tried adding this to my function.php

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
```

And also my page.php has the following:

```
<?php 
                if( has_post_thumbnail() ){
                    the_post_thumbnail( 'post-thumbnail' );
                }
                ?>
```

I have tried disabling all plugins, and have checked the screen options box and there is no option to turn on featured images for standard pages.  Will happily assist with whatever code you need but I am at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `add_support` action is generallly triggered on `after_setup_theme` or `init` action.

You can also use `add_theme_support`,  you will find all details and example [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_theme_support/), this one accepts more parameter to enable support for certains post type only.